# Get fullcalendar JSON from JSP page

Tags: json, jsp, fullcalendar

I'm working with the fullcalendar jQuery plugin and I'm trying to populate my events by creating a JSON object on a jsp page.

Here is what I have for my fullcalendar code...

```
$('#mycalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    editable: false,
    slotMinutes: 5,
    allDaySlot: true,
    lazyFetching: true,
    eventSources: [
        '/servlet/TEST?action=calendarData'
    ],
    eventClick: function(event) {
        if (event.url) {
            window.location.href = event.url;
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I know a lot of my parameters are set as the default, but I only have them set that way for debugging and they will be changed.

The request is going through and is returning what I'm expecting but the event is not getting displayed, which leads me to believe that I'm expecting the wrong thing. Which will probably be evident in my jsp page.

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json;" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
{
    title: "test",
    start: new Date(2011, 3, 12),
    allDay: true
}
```

I'm just trying to hardcode a JSON object to the page so I can better understand what I will need to dynamically create for the real data. I'm expecting this to create an all day event for today. Firebug can read it as a JSON object... but the event is not displaying.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). That's just a JavaScript object literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`eventSources` expects valid JSON](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/eventSources/). The code that's in your page is not [valid JSON](http://json.org/js.html). All keys must be double-quoted, and Dates are not valid values as per [the JSON grammar](http://www.json.org/).

[image: JSON grammar]

Try this:

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json;" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
{
    "title": "test",
    "start": "2011-04-12",
    "allDay": true
}
```

Comment: @Matt Ball, I've tried the double quotes route before and it didn't work. Tried it with your values and I get a new error. `D.start.getDay is not a function` any thoughts?

Comment: @Shaded: yes, because `start` is now a number which you need to parse into a `Date` before handing it off to fullcalendar.

Comment: @Shaded: based on [these fullcalendar docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/) it looks like you can pass a string instead, like `'2010-01-01'` or `'2010-01-09 12:30:00'`. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Matt Ball, Fullcalendar can also accept a UNIX timestamp, so I trimed a few 0's off your time. No more error but still no event showing up.

Comment: Honestly, I've never tried setting up fullcalendar with a JSON feed, so this is total guessing at this point, but you might need to return an array of objects rather than a single object, e.g. `[{"title":"test", ...}]`. See the JSON returned from the demo: http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.1/demos/json-events.php

Comment: @Matt Ball, that was a pretty good total guess, I'm not sure if some other things I tried played into it at all, but the [] brackets did the trick. Thank you very much for your help!